# how to add manual value to date() function

Tags: php

I m in need of adding a defined value to the date() function.
I just want to add 2 more days with the date() function.
suppose `date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); //2014-06-12 05:38:50`
I just want to add 2 more days with the day value which is 12 on above example.
can anyone help ?

Comment: that example was only for date. I need this to add with the time H i s.

Answer (score 1):

use php [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) Object like :

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(new DateInterval('P2D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```